# Error when running linux on vmware

Tags: kali-linux

I recently installed kali linux on vmware version 16. Before kali linux boots up it shows this message;

```
[0.009367][firmware Bug]:CPU 1:APIC Id mismatch Firmware:1 APIC:2
[4.795495]pii×4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus host controller not enabled
[5.508180]sd 2:0:0:0:[sda] assuming drive cache:write through
```

Although kali linux boots up normally but I don't want any errors coming up when I boot up kali linux on vmware. Please guide me on this. Thanks

Comment: In this particular case the only solution would be to obtain hardware that doesn't report conflicting information back depending on whether you ask its APIC or its firmware what its ID is. The other two messages are just diagnostics - a quick self-test shows that there's no SMBus host controller, so the `piix4_smbus` subsystem has nothing to do, and the SCSI subsystem looks at the first (and possibly only) hard drive in your system and assumes it's a write-through drive cache type, because that's the default.

Answer (score 2):

```
[0.009367][firmware Bug]:CPU 1:APIC Id mismatch Firmware:1 APIC:2
```

Unless you can write a custom virtual firmware for VMware, you cannot do anything for this message specifically.

```
[4.795495]pii×4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus host controller not enabled
```

When running on VMware, you won't be able to access the real SMBus of the host system, so you might want to create a file named `/etc/modprobe.d/custom-blacklist.conf` and put the following line into it:

```
blacklist piix4_smbus
```

Then run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to make the change effective in early boot too.

```
[5.508180]sd 2:0:0:0:[sda] assuming drive cache:write through
```

This is an informative message telling you that the (virtual) `sda` disk does not explicitly specify what kind of cache implementation it has. This is pretty normal.

From the [introduction of Kali Linux at kali.org](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/):

> Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT a recommended distribution if you're unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc.
>
> Even for experienced Linux users, Kali can pose some challenges.
>
> [...]
>
> If you are unfamiliar with Linux generally, if you do not have at least a basic level of competence in administering a system, if you are looking for a Linux distribution to use as a learning tool to get to know your way around Linux, or if you want a distro that you can use as a general purpose desktop installation, Kali Linux is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok so if I do what u have posted,will it solve the issue of the firmware bug and SMBus showing up when kali linux is booting up

Comment: You do *not* have the ability to solve the issue of the firmware "bug".